# Не получается правильно массив

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Не могу правильно вывести массив. Пробовал сначала через mysql, так там вообще ничего не получается вывести, попробовал в pdo, получилось что-то вывести, но все равно не то что надо. Но вообще желательно бы, чтоб массив ,был написан в mysql, потому как все остальное у меня в mysql

На картинке показана база, которую нужно вывести в массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сам код, который я написал

```
  $sql= "SELECT post_id, date, author, content, name_image FROM post_en LEFT JOIN image_post ON post_id=id_post_en";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rgOut = [];
foreach ($result as $row) :
        $rgOut[ $row['author'] ] = [$row['name_image']];
endforeach;
```

И получается, что выводит не все имена картинок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И может вообще кто подскажет правильно ли я делаю. У меня есть страница с постами. 
В одном посте может входить какое-то n-ное количество картинок. Поэтому я для того что выделено красным сделал одну таблицу. Для картинок (выделено синим) другую, теперь предположим, что мне нужно вывести какое то количество постов на главной странице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я пытаюсь сделать, или может нужен другой подход. Ну и соответственно, почему не получается массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что всё остальное вы сделали правильно, это код который добавляет, в массив `author` столько `images` сколько у него есть.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT post_id, date, author, content, name_image FROM post_en LEFT JOIN image_post ON post_id=id_post_en');

$rgOut = []; // 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    // Push to array in case that author already in it
    if (isset($rgOut[ $row['author'] ]))
              array_push($rgOut[ $row['author'] ], $row['name_image']);
    else// Create array with the author
        $rgOut[ $row['author'] ] = [$row['name_image']];
}
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало, правда мне бы было проще не pdo, а mysql, но думаю и так пойдет)

Comment: @AlexProsto `PDO` безопастнее. Нажмите, принять ответ, не за что :)

Comment: А можете подсказать как правильней вывести всю информацию, основываясь на таблицу mysql (самая верхняя картинка)

Comment: @AlexProsto у вас два отдельных вопроса, про как выводить и как размещать на странице. Задайте отдельный ворос.

Comment: тогда может подскажите, как полностью вывести массив по скриншоту из базы данных?